# How to add a timestamp for each row inserted using SSIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

I inherited an SSIS project that downloads some files via FTP, unzips them into some weird proprietary format then inserts them into a small datawarehouse. I now need to add a timestamp for each record.  I am pretty new to SSIS - but have seen many people use a derived column task for this type of thing.

So far, I've added a datetime2(2) column on the table in the database, added a derived column task and hooked it up to the destination in my package. I check on the destination in the mappings and ensure that it shows up in there and is mapped.

When I execute this package though, I am only seeing NULLS in the timestamp column.

Here is my derived column:
[image]

I'm also not sure about when I make changes in packages, do I just need to hit "save" to ensure that when, say, a SQL job runs the package my changes will be executed?  There isn't a "publish"/"deploy" type of thing for SSIS packages, right?  This is a bit of a side question, but potentially is related as well? I don't know...

Comment: I just ran a test to be sure, your setup should work fine.  Double check the mapping for the new column is set to your derived column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: don't do this via SSIS if it is a hassle. Add a default of GETDATE() on the new column in the destination table. No need to change the SSIS package this way, guaranteed data in the column each time.

Comment: 4 years later and I'm like... why didn't I just do it this way? Lol

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason derived column would not work. That being said, a way to test it could be to add a script component in between that writes to another column in the DB or out to an excel file. To see if it is getting triggered with every record flowing through it.

The script component would be a simple:
`Row.ColumnName = DateTime.Now;`

This would do the same thing as the derived column albeit with slightly more overhead.

Comment: I think that the derived column is the simplest thing that works.